# Error with Firebase and Environment variables in Vercel and React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firebase's firestore rules are like this

```
rules_version = '2';
cloudservice.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if true;
      allow read, write: if request.origin == "https://......app/";
   allow read, write: if request.origin == "https://...dev/";
   }
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I deployed my project with github and vercel, placing environment variables in the firebase file, and placing the values ​​of the environment variables in vercel and the configuration in firebase pointing to the vercel and cloudflare domains, it still didn't work for me. load my website.

And I see this error:

> Firebase: Error (invalid authentication/api-key)

The project is well configured because when I deploy the same project but without environment variables and placing the values ​​of the firebase apikeys in the same project I don't get any errors and my page loads. Do you know what the error could be? I've been like this for days now.

Comment: Also in authorized domains place the domains.

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate problems here that are not related to each other.

Firstly, what you're trying to do in security rules isn't a feature of Firestore.  There is no `request.origin` to use, and it's not possible to limit traffic that appears to come from some web domain.

Secondly, the error for "invalid authentication/api-key" is saying that you're not passing a valid value to `initializeApp()`.  You should double-check that the object you pass contains everything correctly.  Perhaps log the value before you use it to see what it actually contains.

Comment: The first is not an error in itself, but follow the suggestion so that firebase recognizes the domain, the second is the error, but I tell you that when I pass the true apikeys in the firebase file, I don't get any errors, I get error and my page does not display when I pass the credentials to the firebase file as process.env.Api_key that is when I get an error. And correctly placed the value of the apikey in vercel.